# Likert grouping with different levels in R

Tags: r, grouping

I would like to use the Likert package and also to group by variable and plot the result. The problem is that I have different  levels in the variabels I want to visualise. Is there a way around this ?

A simple example to illustrate my problem:

```
library(reshape)
library(likert)

foo <- data.frame(car = rep(c("Toyota", "BMW", "Ford"), times = 10),
                  satisfaction = c(1,3,4,7,7,6,2,3,5,5,5,2,4,1,7),
                  quality = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,6,4,3,6,6,1,7,2,7),
                  loyalty = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,9,4,3,10,6,1,7,2,8) )

foo[1:4] <- lapply(foo[1:4], as.factor)

likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car)
plot(likt)
```

error message:

```
Error in likert(foo[, c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car) : 
  All items (columns) must have the same number of levels
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as first answer, but now as a function of group.

```
foo[2:4] <- lapply(foo[2:4], factor, levels=1:10)
likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car)
plot(likt)
```

[image: Fig]

Answer (score 2):

Well I can't add a comment until I get more reputation points so I'm breaking the "responding to other answers" guidance - but I wouldn't want other R newbies like me to waste the time I just have figuring out that the line in the original question:

```
library(reshape)
```

breaks the answer provided by Ruthger.

So the code you need to generate Ruthger's plot is just (I tested this with R 3.3.1 having follow the likert installation instructions at the bottom of https://github.com/jbryer/likert):

```
library(likert)

foo <- data.frame(car = rep(c("Toyota", "BMW", "Ford"), times = 10),
                  satisfaction = c(1,3,4,7,7,6,2,3,5,5,5,2,4,1,7),
                  quality = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,6,4,3,6,6,1,7,2,7),
                  loyalty = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,9,4,3,10,6,1,7,2,8) )

foo[2:4] <- lapply(foo[2:4], factor, levels=1:10)
likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car)
plot(likt)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your underlying levels are in reality the same, you just have to tell your data frame that they exist:

```
foo[2:4] <- lapply(foo[2:4], factor, levels=1:9)
```

Then you can plot.  (But how the `grouping` argumnent works remains a mystery - it's not clear from the help of that package.

```
likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)])
plot(likt)
```

[image]

Comment: In the CRAN manual, there is an argument called `nlevels` which seems to do the same work. But I could not find a way to use it correctly.This answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Andrie. Very helpful! Shouldn't levels be levels=1:10? I think adding the grouping variable works as well: likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car).

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Probably.  I could not get the grouping variable to work at all (it's possible that I have an out of date version of the package, though).