# Likert problems with grouping in R

Tags: r, grouping, lapply

I recently asked a question regarding using grouping with the likert package in order to visualise my data. The answer I got worked fine on my example data set.

link: [likert grouping question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061286/likert-grouping-with-different-levels-in-r)
Here was the solution proposal:

```
foo <- data.frame(car = rep(c("Toyota", "BMW", "Ford"), times = 10),
                  satisfaction = c(1,3,4,7,7,6,2,3,5,5,5,2,4,1,7),
                  quality = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,6,4,3,6,6,1,7,2,7),
                  loyalty = c(1,1,3,5,4,3,9,4,3,10,6,1,7,2,8) )



foo[2:4] <- lapply(foo[2:4], factor, levels=1:10)
likt <- likert(foo[,c(2:4)], grouping = foo$car)
plot(likt)
```

However, when I tried this on my dataset I got an error message I was not able to understand:

```
library(reshape)
library(likert)


setwd("C:/mypath")
df<- fread("myfile.csv", select = 1:9)
df <- as.data.frame(df)



#reduce the colnames length
names(df) <- sub("^(.+[:])([^.]+)$", "\\2", names(df))

col_names <- names(df[1:9])
df[,col_names] <- lapply(df[,col_names] , factor, levels = 1:10)
str(df)

df[2:9] <- lapply(df[2:9], factor, levels=1:10)
lik2 <- likert(df[,c(2:9)], grouping = df$Make)
plot(lik2)
```

error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "low", value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 8 rows, data has 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the rookie misstake!!

Should start at the second column sinnce the numerical data starts there.. simple as that..

```
col_names <- names(df[2:9])
```